# Cannot read property '_liveui' of null

Tags: meteor

I'm getting client side errors(console.log ones) but my app works(I can add users)

The error is the following:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_liveui' of null

The project is in my repo:
https://github.com/thiagofm/statusfyit

What is happening?

Comment: I am experiencing a similar problem, this bug affects the events attached to a template

Answer (score 1):

Meteor has updated its API a bunch since this question was asked, so the original code no longer runs directly.

Using jQuery.html to insert the results of rendering a template is not the normal approach. It is better to use the handlebars template include functionality.

For example, replace:

```
$().ready(function(){
  hello = Meteor.ui.render(function(){
    return Template.hello();
  });
  $('body').html(hello);
});
```

With:

```
<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>
```

To render different things depending on the state of the application, use the 'Session' object to conditionalize includes. For example:

```
<template name="foo">
  {{#if showNewUserDialog}}
    {{> newUserDialog}}
  {{else}}
    other stuff
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="newUserDialog">
  some stuff
</template>
```

and

```
Template.foo.showNewUserDialog = function () {
  return Session.get('showNewUserDialog');
};
Template.other.events({
  'click #new_user': function () {
     Session.set('showNewUserDialog', true);
  }
});
```